# How to exchange information between websites?

Tags: php

I'm creating a posting exchange system that allows people to earn points for posting on certain sites. These sites must contain a parser that sends the post counts of the users to the home site where user's points are kept up with in the database.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

How do I get the information from one site's database and send it to another site to be processed?

Comment: are you in charge of all the sites?

Comment: You don't really mean exchange-server do you? You are only talking about websites, correct?

Comment: No I am not in charge of all the sites. This script will be installed by the admins that want to participate in the exchanges. People come from might site and post on all the other sites and earn points in the process. These points are kept up with me but they are earned on other sites.

Comment: an api on your site, would be 'standard' with instructions to the other sites of what to send you. this is kind of broad for a S.O question - i see your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843752/how-to-send-information-to-different-website) was closed for that, its likely to happen here as well

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not on charge of the websites, your best option would be to implement a web service like SOAP or REST.

Comment: To expand on this a bit further, you will want to provide the remote sites with a script that contains the "client" application.  This script will most likely use curl to make requests to your server.  Also, if you need assistance in writing your REST server, there are a number of PHP REST microframeworks out there that can make this really easy.

Comment: Or PHP's SoapClient (http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) should he decide to use SOAP.

Comment: Thanks guys! I don't know much about SOAP or REST but I'll do some research.